# How to bind Object properties upon page submission in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

After reading tutorials and docs I still do not understand the mechanism behind binding certain Object properties in **SpringMVC + hibernate**.

Suppose we have a class `Poem`:

```
package com.test.poems.model;

import com.tastyminerals.poems.model.Author;
import com.tastyminerals.poems.model.Genre;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;


@Entity
@Table(name = "P_POEM")
public class Poem {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="BODY")
    private String body;

    @Column(name="DATE")
    private String date;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID_AUTHOR", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID_GENRE", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Genre genre;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Author getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public Genre getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setAuthor(Author author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public void setGenre(Genre genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

and a class `Author`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AUTHORS")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="ID_AUTHOR")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

/* getters and setters */
```

I need to submit my poem to mysql database via hibernate. For this purpose I created a simple jsp page which has input fields for all Poem properties.
Upon submission `RequestMethod.POST` returns String values for `title`, `body` and author's `name`.

However that creates a type conversion error like: `Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'com.test.model.Author' for property 'author'`.

`Poem` class expects `Author` object to be set into it but getting String `name` instead. I wonder why doesn't Spring make the necessary conversions since I explicitely create `Author` in my controller method? Shouldn't its values be automatically resolved and set after the page submission?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poem/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addPoemPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("poem-add");
        modelAndView.addObject("author", new Author());
        modelAndView.addObject("poem", new Poem());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/poem/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingPoem(@ModelAttribute Poem poem,
            @ModelAttribute Author author) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        authorService.addAuthor(author);

        poem.setAuthor(author);
        poemService.addPoem(poem);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

My jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<c:set var="url">${pageContext.request.requestURL}</c:set>
<link
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/poem-add.css"
    rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Writing a poem</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>New poem</h1>
    <p>Here you can write your poem.</p>
    <form:form method="POST" commandName="poem"
        action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/poem/add.html">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Title:</td>
                    <td><input id="" title="Your poem's title" id="title"
                        name="title" type="text" class="input" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Author:</td>
                    <td><input title="Author's name" id="author" name="author"
                        type="text" class="input" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date:</td>
                    <td><input title="Date of creation" id="date" name="date"
                        type="text" class="input" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Text:</td>
                    <td><textarea title="Your poem goes here" rows="15" cols="50"
                            class="input"> </textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="actions">
            <tr>
                <td><a
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collection.html"><input
                        type="button" value="Back" class="button" /></a></td>
                <td><a
                    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collection.html"><input
                        type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

I know that I need a `PropertyEditor` or `BeanWrapper`. But I simply do not understand where and how do I implement them? What is the difference?

Summing my questions up, I need an explanation of what is going on "behind-the-scenes" between hibernate and SpringMVC right after I click submit button. If you could provide a sample of `PropertyEditor` or `BeanWrapper` for my case I would be endlessly grateful.

Comment: Please add relevent jsp snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need an explanation of what is going on "behind-the-scenes" between
>   hibernate and SpringMVC

: There is no hibernate yet. You are simply mapping a plain bean (model) to a JSP using Spring MVC.

> I know that I need a PropertyEditor or BeanWrapper.

: You don't need a PropertyEditor at this stage. PropertyEditor is used for advanced type conversion like when you want an incoming date string "dd-mm-yyyy Zone" to be converted into a java.util.Date object and vice versa.

> I wonder why doesn't Spring make the necessary
>   conversions since I explicitely create Author in my controller method?
>   Shouldn't its values be automatically resolved and set after the page
>   submission?

:Spring will automatically resolve if the JSP fields are mapped to the model attribute correctly using Spring Form tags. In your case, JSP form fields are not mapped to the model correctly and it should be as below

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="poem"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/poem/add.html">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Title:</td>
                <td><form:input path="poem.title" title="Your poem's title" 
                    type="text" class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Author:</td>
                <td><form:input path="poem.author.name" title="Author's name"
                    type="text" class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Text:</td>
                <td><form:textarea path="poem.body" title="Your poem goes here" rows="15" cols="50"
                        class="input" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="actions">
        <tr>
            <td><a
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collection.html"><input
                    type="button" value="Back" class="button" /></a></td>
            <td><a
                href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/collection.html"><input
                    type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

You can add many attributes to the model but you can attach only one model attribute to the `<form>` and not two. Your controller would look like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/poem/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView addPoemPage() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("poem-add");
        Author author = new Author();
        Poem poem = new Poem();
        poem.setAuthor(author); 
        modelAndView.addObject("poem", new Poem());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/poem/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addingPoem(@ModelAttribute("poem") Poem poem) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("home");
        authorService.addAuthor(poem.getAuthor);
        poemService.addPoem(poem);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that makes sense. I am however getting an exception on jsp page line 25. `org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'poem' of bean class [com.test.poems.model.Poem]: Bean property 'poem' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?`

Comment: this started occuring after I implemented your changes. On `welcome.jsp` I click button which invokes `poem-add.jsp`. It doesn't look like I have discrepancies in my Poem.java.

Comment: Ok. Please update your question with full Poem class, I'll verify the getter and setter methods.

Comment: it's a bit bigger since it also has `Genre`, but the idea of `Genre` is identical to `Author`.

Comment: Are you referring Genre in your JSP? Line 25 in JSP is attaching the model to the form?

Comment: yes, I do -- path="poem.genre.genre". But on Line 25 is `<td><form:input path="poem.title" title="Your poem's title" type="text" class="input" />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54479/discussion-between-minerals-and-javakid).